# Error with new Set in typescript and react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am using react and typescript. I am trying to get unique values from array using 'new Set' and setting the values of a useState. but I am getting the below error

```
argument of type 'Set<string>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<String[]>'.
  Type 'Set<string>[]' is not assignable to type 'String[]'.
    Type 'Set<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'String': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 43 more.ts(2345)
```

Below is my code

```
const [subCategories, setSubCategories] = useState<String[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    return setSubCategories(Array.from([new Set(products.map((p) => p.category))]));
  }, []);
```

products is an array array of object

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

> The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

You are passing an array containing the set into `Array.from()` instead of the set itself, which is already an iterable object:

```
    return setSubCategories(Array.from(new Set(products.map((p) => p.category))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of brackets `[]` inside Array.from() call. You want to do `Array.from(new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']))`;

Another thing is the string type in typescript is represented as `string`. `String` is the class. I can't really think of anything immediately wrong with using `String`, but it's probably not a good idea, definitely uncommon.